# Changing bootstrap button colors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have overridden the bootstrap css for my .domino class with the following mixin:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@mixin button-variant($myBackground, $myColor) {
  background-color: $myBackground;
  color: $myColor;
}
.domino {
  @include button-variant(red, blue);
}
```

The html.erb is:

```
<%= link_to "Domino", domino_path, class: "btn btn-medium btn-info state domino" %>
```

I find that the button color (the text) does indeed change to $myColor (blue), but the background remains unaltered. This means that the 'btn-info' class, as far as background color is concerned, is 'dominant' over the domino class. What determines which css is dominant over other css? Why does the color change but not the background color?

The HTML produced is:

```
<a class="btn btn-medium btn-info state domino" href="/dominos/11">Domino</a>
```

Comment: Seems good. Can you give us the generated HTML please ?

Comment: Why are you keeping btn-info there? If you want to override, wouldn't you get rid of btn-info and just keep domino? Also, it matters where everything is located in your final .css file. CSS goes top down in overriding colors. So if domino is above btn-info, btn-info will have precedence.

Comment: I've added the HTML.
I'm not sure about the order of code in the final css file. As I understand it, it is all compiled into the manifest file application.css, and I'm not sure how to view the combined file. Is it possible?

Comment: Removing btn-info does not solve the problem. With this change, the background color changes to white, no matter what color I request via $myColor.
Clearly the only solution is to fully understand the order of code and how the manifest file is assembled?

Comment: Don't the Bootstrap button classes use gradients?  If so, you have to override the *background-image* portion of the background as well.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. I found this, which is awesome:
http://charliepark.org/bootstrap_buttons/